# $lookup,$match is giving an empty array in mongodb using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EabR.png) is my GUI of db
 I am trying to get the data from two collection based on $match, $lookup in mongodb using nodejs , The resulting array is coming as empty even though data in my collections is correct. Below is my code.Partner,Sample are my two collections
    Mongosb version : 3.4 , mongoose version : 5.1.2

```
     Partner.aggregate([{ $match: { email: req.user.user.email } }, 
            {
                $lookup:
                {
                  from: 'sampleProcess',
                  localField: '_id',
                  foreignField: 'partnerid',
                  as:'data'
                }
        }], function (err, data) {
            if (err) res.json(err); console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
            if (data) console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); res.json(data);
        })}
```

My Partner collection data

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b22433324a9d70a58c1a4a4"),
    "partnerName" : "indraja",
    "email" : "indrajaboya@gmail.com",
    "mobileNo" : 232323232323.0,
    "addressLine1" : "banaswadi",
    "addressLine2" : "banglore",
    "city" : "bangalore"
}
```

My sample Collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b22540fb45a893624ab214d"),
    "sampleStatus" : "Sample Sent",
    "sampleService" : "Translation",
    "sampleSentTat" : "6",
    "partnerid" : ObjectId("5b22433324a9d70a58c1a4a4"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: can you please post your sample collections

Comment: I edited my post with collection

Comment: I tried it is not working

Comment: Your `partenerid` seems to be a string value... Is it? It should be an `ObjectId`

Comment: yes it is string  now i changed to objectid still resulting array is empty only,{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b24aa53677d271070bf89e5"),
    "sampleStatus" : "Sample Sent",
    "sampleService" : "Translation",
    "sampleSentTat" : "6",
    "partnerid" : ObjectId("5b24aa40677d271070bf89e2"),
    "__v" : 0
}  is my update sample collection

Comment: I updated my post with screenshot of  gui in the above of my post with name screenshot

Comment: partnerid i have given it as string changed to objectId